# Spring controller not invoking @Valid

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I know this question was asked a few times here but i could not find an answer to help me

I am trying to use the `@Valid` annotation on my controller, but spring doesn't seem to want to do anything with it

Here is what i am doing:

Versions:

```
<org.springframework-version>4.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
<hibernate-annotations-version>3.5.6-Final</hibernate-annotations-version>
```

Class i want to validate:

```
public class myclass{

private int                 id;

@NotEmpty
@Min(20)
private String              title;

@NotEmpty
private String              description;
}
```

Controller signature:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ServerResponse<Integer> addSomeClass(@RequestBody @Valid myclass mymy) {
```

I also configured

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

private @Value("${web.maxFileUploadSize}") int MAX_FILE_UPLOAD_SIZE;

public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/deployed/**").addResourceLocations("/deployed/");
}

@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver ret = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    ret.setMaxUploadSize(MAX_FILE_UPLOAD_SIZE);
    return ret;
}

@Bean
public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter(){
    RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter = new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new LinkedList<>();
    messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    requestMappingHandlerAdapter.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
    return requestMappingHandlerAdapter;
}

@Bean(name ="validator")
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator(){
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}
}
```

when i send this JSON:

```
{"title":"","description":""}
```

nothing happens and everything continues.

Cant seem to find the answer.

**UPDATE**

I already had:

```
<hibernate-validator-version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate-validator-version>
```

So i updated it to: `5.1.1` and this is what i get

> ```
>  Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
> at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:154)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
> at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
> at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
> at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343)
> at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431)
> at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
> ... 74 more
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ParameterNameProvider
> at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:41)
> at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:269)
> at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
> at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:459)
> at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.activate(TypeSafeActivator.java:97)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:148)
> ... 82 more
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ParameterNameProvider
> at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
> at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
> ... 92 more
> ```

so i updated my `validation-api` to `1.1.0.Final` no exception but still no validation as well

Comment: ofcorse... its under my Configuration EnableWebMvc class

Comment: `@RequestBody` [supports bean validation as well](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java#L55). You should try to debug it. Note, that the validator [might need to be propertly configured](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html#getValidator()). Otherwise default instance is provided (which is equivalent to your configuration).

Comment: Maybe show us the whole MVC configuration. Are you using standard `@EnableWebMvc`?

Comment: @PavelHoral Spring documentation says that the default configuration is enough

Comment: You show hibernate-annotations version. If its not a typo, hibernate-validator (which you want) is different from hibernate-annotations (which deals with ORM persistance)

Comment: Can you provide the sample maven project?

Answer (score 3):

Try and pass BindingResult on your controller signature exactly after (myclass mymy), like this

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ServerResponse<Integer> addSomeClass(@RequestBody @Valid myclass mymy, BindingResult result) {
```

This usually works for me, hope it does for you as well.......!

Comment: Yes I think this one is also relevant, although it depends on other implementation details of the controller, e.g. if there is an ExceptionHandler for bad requests etc.

Answer (score 1):

Add the Hibernate Validator dependency to your POM.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more information about your project setup. What spring version do you use? Do you use spring mvc? If so please check if you have an [JSR-303 Validator in your classpath](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-mvc-jsr303). The newest spring version should automagically detect it and pick it up.

Besides that you have to [provide a LocalValidatorFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring) to make the validaton work.

```
@Configuration
public class ValidationConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean()
    {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);

        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel it is necessary to see your pom, or at least the part that is relevant for this issue. I am pretty sure that this is some version mismatch between dependencies. Here is a combination that might work, given your spring version:

```
<properties>
<spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>



<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring  dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate Validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

=========== EDIT ==========

Just want to add that it would also be valuable to see more implementation details for the controller. The approach you use would presumably work (given you have the correct combination of artifacts) if you provide a default error handler. If not you would have to do something like @Aph1ka suggests. Here are some of the possibilities:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "foo")
public class SomeController {
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public ServerResponse<Integer> addSomeClass(@RequestBody @Valid myclass mymy) {
        ....
  }

  @ExceptionHandler
  @ResponseBody
  @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  public Error handleException(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception) {
      return new ApiErrors(exception.getBindingResult());
  }

}
```

or

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ServerResponse<Integer> addSomeClass(@RequestBody @Valid myclass mymy, Errors errors) {
  if (errors.hasErrors()) {
     // return error some view e.g.
     return new ResponseEntity(new ApiErrors(errors), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  }
  //....
}
```

or, as @Aph1ka hints at:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ServerResponse<Integer> addSomeClass(@RequestBody @Valid myclass mymy, BindingResult result) {
  if (result.hasErrors()) {
    // return some error view
  }
  // ....
}
```

Comment: make sure that you mvn clean also, when making such changes to the pom

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when testing a controller. Validation was not taking place when added like this:

`@InitBinder("multimediaParams")`

But worked without names, like this:

`@InitBinder`

As we have added a second validator, the last option is no longer possible. So instead of doing this in the tests:

```
Object handler = handlerMapping.getHandler(request).getHandler();
handlerAdapter.handle(request, response, handler);
```

We now have added the specific validator manually:

```
ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer webBindingInitializer = new ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer();
webBindingInitializer.setValidator(multimediaValidator);
handlerAdapter.setWebBindingInitializer(webBindingInitializer);

Object handler = handlerMapping.getHandler(request).getHandler();
handlerAdapter.handle(request, response, handler);
```

This way the validation takes place again as expected. Not beautiful, but works.

Answer (score -1):

1. `@NotEmpty` is Hibernate specific you should use `@NotNull` if you want to validate your beans through JSR-303.
2. You can use BindingResult to verify as suggested by `@Aph1ka`.
3. You can have a look at spring mvc showcase for a working example.
   [pom.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/pom.xml)
   [validation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase/tree/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/validation)

Comment: @dhipin-k-das why vote down? Check rules http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down . "What are the alternatives to down-voting?" is there any grudge?

Comment: I didn't down-vote Someone else did! I only improved your answer formatting. Check for yourself!